# Huge delay when using Celery + Redis

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery

I'm testing Django + Celery, hello world examples. With RabbitMQ celery works fine, but when I switched to Redis broker/result I get following:

```
%timeit add.delay(1,2).get()
1 loops, best of 3: 503 ms per loop
```

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Is there any issues in test above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution is source code:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/result.html#AsyncResult.get

> **interval** – Time to wait (in seconds) before retrying to retrieve the result. Note that this does not have any effect when using the
>   amqp result store backend, as it does not use polling.

By default it is 0.5 sec. You can change it manually, but it's not recommended way for running tasks:

```
%timeit add.delay(1,2).get(interval=0.001)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 ms per loop
```