# How do Celery run multiple tasks so slow with Python?

Tags: python, celery

My celery start with amqp

```
     -------------- celery@tty-Gazelle-Professional v3.0.19 (Chiastic Slide)
     ---- **** ----- 
     --- * ***  * -- Linux-3.8.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-13.04-raring
     -- * - **** --- 
     - ** ---------- [config]
     - ** ---------- .> broker:      amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
     - ** ---------- .> app:         proj.celery:0x25ed510
     - ** ---------- .> concurrency: 8 (processes)
     - *** --- * --- .> events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
     -- ******* ---- 
     --- ***** ----- [queues]
     -------------- .> celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery
```

There is a function:

```
    def prime(n):
        .....
        .....
        return number_of_primes_below_n
```

So I made this function as a task in celery and compared to serial computation

The serial:

```
    [prime(i) for i in xrange(10, 100000)]
```

The parallel with celery:

```
    from celery import *
    
    g = group(prime.s(i) for i in xrange(10, 100000))
    res = g.apply_async()
```

when I apply_async(), in the backend the result showing on the terminal screen very quickly like:

```
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,238: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[989be06b-c4f3-4876-9311-2f5f813857d5] succeeded in 0.0166230201721s: 99640324
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,241: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[6eaa9b85-7ba2-4397-b6ae-cbb5668633d4] succeeded in 0.0123620033264s: 99740169
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,242: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[1f5f6302-94a3-4937-9914-14690d856a5d] succeeded in 0.00850105285645s: 99780121
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,244: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[b3735842-a49c-48a3-8a9e-fab24c0a6c23] succeeded in 0.0102620124817s: 99820081
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,245: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[98eec31a-52eb-4752-92af-6956c0e6f130] succeeded in 0.00973200798035s: 99880036
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,245: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[011a1e99-b307-480b-9765-b1a472dbfa8c] succeeded in 0.0115168094635s: 99800100
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,245: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[f3e3a89f-de79-4ab0-aab7-0a71fe2ab2f7] succeeded in 0.010409116745s: 99840064
[2013-06-20 16:34:56,246: INFO/MainProcess] Task proj.tasks.do_work[61baef04-03c2-4810-bf6a-ae7aa75b80b4] succeeded in 0.0112910270691s: 99860049
```

but when I would like to get the result in celery with

```
    res.get()
```

it runs very very slow, much slower than serial. What is the problem? Is it because the getting results from celery group is slow? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If you need more speed, just add more workers. Workers can be running in other machines as well. This is the whole point of using AMQP, if you are not allowed to throw hardware at the problem perhaps celery is overkill.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thank you so much Paulo, as you see from the top, concurrency: 8 (processes), can I add 8 workers to do group()? Thanks

Comment: If it is CPU-intensive, there is no point in running more workers than you have cores - if you have other machines to spare, use them, on the other hosts use the real IP address of the AMQP server instead of localhost (don't run one AMQP server on each machine, point all machines to the same server). If it is I/O intensive keep pumping it up while the I/O wait is bellow 1 or 2 (last column of `vmstat 10 10`).

Comment: @PauloScardine I added two more workers, actually every worker calculate their own part, which means it runs parallel, and in the backend I am able to see the results printing. However when I do res.ready() or res.get(), it always hangs there, but I am sure all workers finish their part.

Comment: For a large result it could be expensive maintaining state in the queue, you may try to store it in a database instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you timeit res.get() operation you'll notice(I hope it's true), that is always about 500 ms. This is because **AsyncResult.get** have to poll for result every **N** milliseconds. You can adjust this by providing additional parameter for get, **interval**:

```
res.get(interval=0.005)
```

You can get more information [in documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html) and [source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/result.html#AsyncResult.get). Be warn, Celery is not best solution for RPC-like communication, because polling for results cause big performance hit.

[My own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386431/huge-delay-when-using-celery-redis)

Comment: Note there's a new 'rpc' backend in the upcoming Celery 3.1 that is optimized for this :)

Comment: That is, it is non-persistent and only the process that initiates the task can retrieve the result (request-reply pattern)

Comment: @asksol, thank you. Can you give some link/example how this 'rpc' backend works? I didn't find anything in documentation.

Comment: This is a great answer to something that is not easy to find the in the documentation.